# Reading a Json Array in android

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to read a JSON array. Here is my code.

```
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);

        System.out.println("*****JARRAY*****"+jArray.length());
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){


                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("log_tag","_id"+json_data.getInt("account")+
                        ", mall_name"+json_data.getString("name")+
                        ", location"+json_data.getString("number")+
                        ", telephone"+json_data.getString("url")+
                        ",----"+json_data.getString("balance")+
                        ",----"+json_data.getString("credit")+
                        ",----"+json_data.getString("displayName")
                );

        }
```

And my sample JSON files syntax is as follows,

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "account": 1,
            "name": "card",
            "number": "xxxxx xxxx xxxx 2002",
            "url": "http://www.google.com",
            "balance": 1.0,
            "credit": 1.0,
            "displayName": "hsbc bank" 
        },
        {
            "account": 2,
            "name": "card2",
            "number": "xxxxx xxxx xxxx 3003",
            "url": "http://www.google.com",
            "balance": 2.0,
            "credit": 2.0,
            "displayName": "nsb bank" 
        } 
    ],
    "count": 2
}
```

It has a curly brace in front. When i try to execute this code block it gives an error saying

> A JSONArray text must start with '['
>   at character 1 of....

Has anyone encountered a problem like this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Please show me a sample code block if can. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

A JSON Object starts with a `{` and ends with a `}` while a JSON Array starts with a `[` and ends with a `]`.

In your case, change your code to have a `JSONObject` instead.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("list");

System.out.println("*****JARRAY*****" + jArray.length());

for(int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++){
    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

    Log.i("log_tag", "_id" + json_data.getInt("account") +
        ", mall_name" + json_data.getString("name") +
        ", location" + json_data.getString("number") +
        ", telephone" + json_data.getString("url") +
        ",----" + json_data.getString("balance") +
        ",----" + json_data.getString("credit") +
        ",----" + json_data.getString("displayName")
    );
}
```

Comment: Great, glad to have been of help. Don't forget to **accept** an answer! :-)

Answer (score 8):

You first need to create a JSONObject to get the Array from, something like this should work:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("list");
```

Answer (score 3):

String result = js.getString("Result");

```
                    JSONArray js2 = new JSONArray(result);
                    for (int i = 0; i < js2.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject js3 = js2.getJSONObject(i);
                        categoriescity.add(js3.getString("Title"));
                    }
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much, Rashid Mirazimi. You saved my day.