# How to return data from php to eclipse?

Tags: php, android, mysql

Hi, I am using php to get the data from mysql database and upon successful receiving of the data I call a new activity where I need to print the data.

This is my code:

```
public class RecoProd extends Activity {
    EditText pd;
    TextView error;

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recomain);
        pd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);

        error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);

        pd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product", pd
                        .getText().toString()));


                // String valid = "1";

                DownloadWebPageTask dw = new DownloadWebPageTask();
                dw.execute("");

            }
        });
    }

    private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String response = null;
            for (String url : urls) {
                try {
                    response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/abc/check2.php", postParameters);  
                    String res = response.toString();
                    // res = res.trim();
                    res = res.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    // error.setText(res);
                    if(res.equals("1")){     ***<<--------------I think the error is here***
                        Intent loginintent = new Intent(RecoProd.this, RecoProd1.class);
                        startActivity(loginintent);
                    }
                    else
                        error.setText("Sorry!! ");





                } catch (Exception e) {


                }
            }
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        }
    }
}
```

This is my php code:

```
<?php
$pd=$_POST['name'];

//connect to the db
$user = "root";
$pswd = "";
$db = "mylogin";
$host = "localhost";
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd);
mysql_select_db($db);

$query = "SELECT * FROM recoprod  ";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recoprod");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $output[]=$row;
  }
/*
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to verify user because : " . mysql_error());
//this is where the actual verification happens  
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)  
echo 1;  // for correct login response  
else  
echo 0; // for incorrect login response */
?>
```

I am getting a force close when I execute it.

```
EDITED CODE





package com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class RecoProd extends Activity {
    EditText pd;
    TextView error;

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        try {
            Class<?> strictModeClass = Class.forName("android.os.StrictMode", true, Thread.currentThread()
                    .getContextClassLoader());

            Class<?> threadPolicyClass = Class.forName("android.os.StrictMode$ThreadPolicy", true, Thread
                    .currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

            Class<?> threadPolicyBuilderClass = Class.forName("android.os.StrictMode$ThreadPolicy$Builder", true,
                    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

            Method setThreadPolicyMethod = strictModeClass.getMethod("setThreadPolicy", threadPolicyClass);

            Method detectAllMethod = threadPolicyBuilderClass.getMethod("detectAll");
            Method penaltyMethod = threadPolicyBuilderClass.getMethod("penaltyLog");
            Method buildMethod = threadPolicyBuilderClass.getMethod("build");

            Constructor<?> threadPolicyBuilderConstructor = threadPolicyBuilderClass.getConstructor();
            Object threadPolicyBuilderObject = threadPolicyBuilderConstructor.newInstance();

            Object obj = detectAllMethod.invoke(threadPolicyBuilderObject);

            obj = penaltyMethod.invoke(obj);
            Object threadPolicyObject = buildMethod.invoke(obj);
            setThreadPolicyMethod.invoke(strictModeClass, threadPolicyObject);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String TAG = null;
            Log.w(TAG, ex);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recomain);
        pd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);

        error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showresult);

        pd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product", pd
                        .getText().toString()));


                // String valid = "1";

                DownloadWebPageTask dw = new DownloadWebPageTask();
                dw.execute("");

            }
        });
    }

    private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String response = null;
            for (String url : urls) {
                try {
                    response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/abc/check2.php", postParameters);  
                    String res = response.toString();
                    // res = res.trim();
                    res = res.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    // error.setText(res);
                    try{
                        res = "";
                  JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(res);
                        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.i("prod_id","id: "+json_data.getInt("prod_id")+
                                        ", prod_name: "+json_data.getString("prod_name")+
                                        ", prod_category: "+json_data.getInt("prod_category")+
                                        ", prod_cost: "+json_data.getInt("prod_cost")
                                );
                                //Get an output to the screen
                                res += "\n" + json_data.getString("prod_id") + " -> "+ json_data.getInt("prod_name");
                        }
                }
                catch(JSONException e){
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                }

                try{
                 error.setText(res);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                 Log.e("log_tag","Error in Display!" + e.toString());;          
                }   
           }
                 catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());     
           }
            }
            return response;

               }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        }
    }
}
```

This is my php code:

```
<?php
$pd = $_POST['name'];

//connect to the db
$user = "root";
$pswd = "";
$db = "mylogin";
$host = "localhost";
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd);
mysql_select_db($db);

$query = "SELECT * FROM recoprod  ";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recoprod");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $output[] = $row;
}
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
/*
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to verify user because : " . mysql_error());
//this is where the actual verification happens  
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)  
echo 1;  // for correct login response  
else  
echo 0; // for incorrect login response */
?>
```

Hi, I made some changes check the above edited code.

And I have only 2 rows which I am fetching with each row containing 4 data.

Comment: i dont have any logcat error i think the error is in the php file where i return the data i think i am not doing it properly.

Comment: try to echo your result in server console or either in your local host .and surround your code with try catch to get the exception while executing Asyntask

Comment: You are trying to fetch all the row in recoprod table and loop them. If your table has more number of records, then 'while' loop will take more time to complete the execution. So you have to wait until completion of loop by change 'Maximum execution time' in php.ini file.

Comment: how to do that can you edit the above code and show?? @hilarudeens

Comment: If your are using XAMPP, Then go to the file path "...\xampp\php.ini" and edit "max_execution_time = <some seconds in number>". And set that to '0' to make wait as long as complete execution of current request.

Comment: Sorry the path is "...\xampp\php\php.ini"

Comment: hi i dont have that file...

Comment: Hi @hilarudeens i have updated my code can you check and tell what is wrong please.

Comment: @Jayant Your code at server side is fine. Debug the your client code. To ensure the correctness of your server side hit the page from browser. I don't have enough knowledge in android, go for some android experts help

Comment: If you're not using XAMPP, just locate your php.ini file. You can check which one is in use just by creating a php file with `phpinfo();` in it (Don't use this in production!!).

Comment: Another little piece of advice: don't use straight mysql_* functions, try the object oriented versions http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Comment: Can you provide some more details about the error you're getting?

Comment: what more information do you need??

Comment: An exception for start would be great?

Comment: no exception its printing in the log cat but not showing in the emulator

Comment: do u send multiple request to server at a time?

Comment: nobody complains about the fact that he's using root to log into the mysql server?

I would say that would be a first to adress...

Comment: @JayantShinde : what u are getting in this line `String res = response.toString();` ? and also add `CustomHttpClient` class code

Comment: -1 for lack of stacktrace.

Comment: read the above comments please i told you i didnt get any errors....

Comment: Please post your `CustomHttpClient` code.

Answer (score 2):

your problem is on AsyncTask Part

as you use AsyncTask you can process data on doInBackground function BUT Update UI ON  onPostExecute.
 return processed value to onPostExecute as using AsyncTask on android  allow you to change things on layout after it done load. but only on onPostExecute state so process your json on doInBackground then reflect that to layout on onPostExecute

```
public class RecoProd extends Activity {
EditText pd;
TextView error;

ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recomain);
    pd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);

    error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);

    pd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product", pd
                    .getText().toString()));


            // String valid = "1";

            DownloadWebPageTask dw = new DownloadWebPageTask();
            dw.execute("");

        }
    });
}

private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = null;
        for (String url : urls) {
            try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/abc/check2.php", postParameters);  
                String res = response.toString();
                // res = res.trim();
                res = res.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                // error.setText(res);






            } catch (Exception e) {


            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

         if(result.equals("1")){    
             Intent loginintent = new Intent(RecoProd.this, RecoProd1.class);
             startActivity(loginintent);
         }
         else
             error.setText("Sorry!! ");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: if you got error make your  "String res" defination   above the try case

Comment: Also if you like to fix your second modified code your problem was that you update ui at this line

                 error.setText(res);
on doInBackground - move it to onPostExecute and return res as result on your doInBackground

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

```
public class RecoProd extends Activity {
EditText pd;
TextView error;

ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recomain);
    pd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);

    error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);

    pd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product", pd
                    .getText().toString()));


            // String valid = "1";

            downloadWebPageTask();

        }
    });
}

private void downloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2/abc/check2.php?postParameters=paramValue";
    grabURL(url);
}


public void grabURL(String url){
    try {
        new GrabURL().execute(new URL(url));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class GrabURL extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        // This method will send the http request
        JSONObject jsonResponse=null;
        try 
        {
            URL link = urls[0];
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(link.toString());
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpClient.execute(request, responseHandler);
            jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responseBody);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return jsonResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // This method will be executed before the http request
        // In this method you can do things like showing the loading sign
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObj) {
        // This method will run after the http request and contains the results
        // This method expectes you return a valid jSon from the server
        try {
            if(! jsonObj.getString("code").equalsIgnoreCase("200") ){
                // Bad response from server
            }
            else if( jsonObj.has("data") ){
                JSONArray dataArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

                String tmpUserLoc = (String) jsonObj.getJSONObject("data").get("userLocation");
                String tempUserNIC = (String) jsonObj.getJSONObject("data").get("userNIC");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // You can stop the loading sign here if you showed it in OnPreExecute
    }

}
```

}

I haven't tested this code but it should work. If you are returning jSon Array from the server you might want to take a look at [jSonArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) doc OR [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244879/reading-a-json-array-in-android) could also be helpful.