# How to check if response from server is JSONAobject or JSONArray?

Tags: android, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine whether JSON is a JSONObject or JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118708/determine-whether-json-is-a-jsonobject-or-jsonarray)

I have a server that returns some JSONArray by default, but when some error occurs it returns me JSONObject with error code. I'm trying to parse json and check for errors, I have piece of code that checks for error:

```
public static boolean checkForError(String jsonResponse) {

    boolean status = false;
    try {

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);

        if (json instanceof JSONObject) {

            if(json.has("code")){
                int code = json.optInt("code");
                if(code==99){
                    status = true;
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return status ;
}
```

but I get JSONException when jsonResponse is ok and it's a JSONArray (JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONOBject)How to check if jsonResponse will provide me with JSONArray or JSONObject ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`JSONTokener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html). The [`JSONTokener.nextValue()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html#nextValue()) will give you an `Object` that can be dynamically cast to the appropriate type depending on the instance.

```
Object json = new JSONTokener(jsonResponse).nextValue();
if(json instanceof JSONObject){
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)json;
    //further actions on jsonObjects
    //...
}else if (json instanceof JSONArray){
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray)json;
    //further actions on jsonArray
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying the convert String response you get from Server into `JSONObject` which is causing the Exception. As you said you will get the `JSONArray` from Server, you try to convert into `JSONArray`. Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244879/reading-a-json-array-in-android) which will help you when to convert string response to `JSONObject` and `JSONArray`. If you response starts with [ (Open Square Bracket) then convert it to JsonArray as below

```
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(jsonResponse);
```

if your response starts with { (open flower Bracket) then convert it to

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
```