# Android check if server response "is" a JSON

Tags: java, php, javascript, android, json

Like you know, a php `mysql_query()` request returns `false` if the query was not successful. With time, I formed a habit (you should tell me if it's a bad one) to make something like

```
$res = mysql_query(...);

if($res == false){
    echo json_encode("notOK");
}else{
    $return = array();
    // process query result into that array
    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

The processing of the response works well in JavaScript by doing something like

```
// (...)
success : function(response){
    var res = JSON.parse(resonse);
    if(res == "notOK"){
        // error handling
    }else{
        // proceed 
    }
}
// (...)
```

However, in Android this seems not to work. My standard process to handle the server request is

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response;
Vector<JSONObject> vector = new Vector<JSONObject>();

try{
    response = client.execute(get);         
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    if(entity != null){
        InputStream in = entity.getContent();
        String result = convertStreamtoString(in);

        JSONArray resultArray = new JSONArray(result);

        int len = resultArray.length();

        for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
            vector.add(resultArray.getJSONObject(i));
        }

        in.close();
    }
} catch (//...
```

This results in a `JSONException` which reads

```
04-14 17:13:23.011: W/System.err(433): org.json.JSONException: Value true of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
04-14 17:13:23.022: W/System.err(433):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
04-14 17:13:23.022: W/System.err(433):  at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:91)
04-14 17:13:23.022: W/System.err(433):  at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
04-14 17:13:23.022: W/System.err(433):  at imhotapp.schlettibusiness.rest.RestHandler.login(RestHandler.java:52)
04-14 17:13:23.022: W/System.err(433):  at imhotapp.schlettibusiness.LoginActivity.tryLogin(LoginActivity.java:48)
04-14 17:13:23.030: W/System.err(433):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 17:13:23.030: W/System.err(433):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-14 17:13:23.030: W/System.err(433):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
04-14 17:13:23.030: W/System.err(433):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-14 17:13:23.030: W/System.err(433):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-14 17:13:23.030: W/System.err(433):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-14 17:13:23.030: W/System.err(433):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-14 17:13:23.030: W/System.err(433):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-14 17:13:23.030: W/System.err(433):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-14 17:13:23.030: W/System.err(433):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 17:13:23.030: W/System.err(433):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-14 17:13:23.030: W/System.err(433):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-14 17:13:23.030: W/System.err(433):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-14 17:13:23.030: W/System.err(433):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there a way to handle that like in Javascript? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

PS: I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685777/how-to-check-if-response-from-server-is-jsonaobject-or-jsonarray) here, but i do not think that it is a duplicate, because here it's about checking if an object is even 'JSON-familiar' or not

Comment: you need to add a `catch` statement for that specific error. A `try` without a `catch` does nothing (that I know of) in Java.

Comment: if you post the actual json you're getting back, it would also be helpful.  It looks like it's just "true", which obviously can't be converted to an array.

Comment: @Dave of course I'm doing error handlin, just edited my question. @Sam Dufel indeed it is, but how can this be processed like in JS (I know that there a `var` hasn't a specific type when declared).

Comment: @ValentinoRu : Why don't you just use `if ("notOK".equals(result))` before you try to create your `JSONArray`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem is that sometimes your returned data represents a JSON object, and other times it represents a JSON array. Your Android code is treating the data as an array in all cases. You ***can*** handle this, but not with the JSON.org library you are using now. Since you are developing for Android you have built in access to the Gson library - and with it you can do this:

```
JSONElement jsonElem = new JsonParser().parse(result);
if(jsonElem.isJsonArray()) {
    // Normal data
} else {
    // 'Error' data'
}
```

Pretty simple. Do note however that you should really indicate error conditions with an appropriate HTTP status code (one of the 50x codes), as opposed to just relying on the returned data.

Answer (score 0):

According to : http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt
is should be "application/json".

boolean isJSON = "application/json".equalsIgnoreCase(entity.getContentType());

Comment: OP is sending JSON in both cases.