# Receiving multiple JSON objects(arrays) in java(Eclipse)

Tags: java, php, android, json, eclipse

I try to get this json encoded output from php

```
$response["success"] = $id;
echo json_encode($response);
echo json_encode($eventid);
```

while $response only contains an integer at ["success] and $eventid contains an array of ids(for example ["1","3"]).
So the php file output is for example like this:

```
{"success":"3"}["1","3","7"]
```

Now I try to get both the success, and the eventid. I get the success with

```
int id = json.getInt("success");
```

and it works, the problem is to get the array of eventids.
I found this post: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244879/reading-a-json-array-in-android) but it wasn't helpful for me, because I don't have tags for each single element in the array.
So the question is whether I do have to add tags for every single element, or there is another Syntax which I can use?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it would be better if u add tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The provided JSON is not valid. You need to modify it to look like this:

```
{
    "success": "3",
    "elements": [
        "1",
        "3",
        "7"
    ]
}
```

If you do that, you will be able to do this:

```
JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray ("elements");
for (int counter = 0; counter < array.length (); counter ++)
   Log.d ("element", array.getInt (counter));
```

Comment: Glad to help out. You could mark it as the selected answer if it solved your problem completely.

Answer (score 2):

I would encode `$eventid` within `$response` just like you did with `$success`

```
$response["success"] = $id;
$response["eventid"] = $eventid;
echo json_encode($response);
```

yields:

```
{"success":3,"eventid":[ 1, 3, 7]}
```

Comment: Well damnit, can't give two people solved can you? How about an upvote  if mine wasn't the best answer.

Comment: yeah it was definetely a possible answer to my specific problem, but shade's is more universal, for sure i upvoted your's (: