# How to read json array in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am facing here problem in reading a json array which is got from server : http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9090/appsapi/rest/services/getStudentPersonalDetails/123789 , this json   array doesn't have json object in it. It is like below.:

```
{"password":"raj","address":"dfsaf","state":"tamilnadu","image":"Bindu Appalam.jpg",
 "dept":"BE(Mech)","fname":"fasdf","mname":"saffd","dob":"14/12/1951","sex":"Male",
 "email":"fdasd@gmail.com","contact":"212121212545855555545","city":"dsfadf",
 "pin":"600106","sname":"fdjsf","studid":"123789"}
```

I want to parse it..

I have tried to get the json array like below from httpclient request :

```
try {

            System.out.println("url tt : "+url);
            // http client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            System.out.println(" Urls Input to "+url);

            // Checking http request method type
            if (method == POST) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                // adding post params
                if (params != null) {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                }

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } else if (method == GET) {
                // appending params to url
                System.out.println(" Params Valyes "+params);

                if (params != null) {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                    System.out.println(" Params String "+paramString);
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            }

            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but got below error in response :

```
05-20 16:38:25.420: I/System.out(29983):  
Output <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.5 - Error report
</title><style type="text/css">H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} 
H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} 
H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} 
BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} 
B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} 
P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name
 {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}</style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 - Not Found
</h1><div class="line"></div><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Not Found</u></p><p><b>description</b>
 <u>The requested resource is not available.</u></p><hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.5</h3></body></html>
```

any body , pls help here...

Comment: Looks like you are getting 404 not found on your service call? It cant parse it because it cant be found

Comment: I think so your json is wrong

Comment: could you give us the correct url?

Comment: raj is in the double quote

Comment: @Vijay, sorry it is in double quetes there , i mistakenly did that, will edit it..

Answer (score 1):

A JSON Object starts with a { and ends with a } while a JSON Array starts with a [ and ends with a ].

In your case, change your code to have a JSONObject instead.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("list");

System.out.println("*****JARRAY*****"+jArray.length());
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){


 JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
 Log.i("log_tag","_id"+json_data.getInt("account")+
  ", mall_name"+json_data.getString("name")+
  ", location"+json_data.getString("number")+
  ", telephone"+json_data.getString("url")+
  ",----"+json_data.getString("balance")+
  ",----"+json_data.getString("credit")+
  ",----"+json_data.getString("displayName")
 );

}
```

refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/a/4244963/2771869

Answer (score 1):

Kindly refer online for how to get JSON Response.

http://mrbool.com/how-to-use-json-to-parse-data-into-android-application/28944

Answer (score 1):

In your code, there is no json array present, it is json object with name value pair data. So you have to parse `JSONObject` not `JSONArray`.

Like:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);

String password = json.getString("password");
```

Similarly you can get all the values of the object.

Comment: hi, thnks for reply my problem is here in getting response from server using httpclient.. i am getting here Http not found error..